# Retrieving array of assets in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I´ve defined this model:

```
asset Ask identified by askId
{
    o String askId
    o String title
    o String[] options
    o Integer[] votes
}


asset Poll identified by pollId
{
    o String pollId
    --> Ask[] asks
}
```

and when I try to get the asks field I am not able to get anything. Here is the test code:

```
count.poll.asks.forEach(function(ask)
{
       alert("Ask:" +ask);
});
```

An `alert(count.poll)` retrieves `Relationship {id=org.acme.democracity.Poll#pollId:poll1111}` so there is a valid object within.

I´m not sure even if it´s possible to declare an assets array as I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to recreate you models and make the function, here is what I had:

```
asset Ask identified by askId
{
    o String askId
    o String title
    o String[] options
    o Integer[] votes
}


asset Poll identified by pollId
{  
    o String pollId
    --> Ask[] asks
}

transaction count {
    --> Poll pollId
}
```

And my transaction processor function looked like:

```
/**
 * count transaction
 * @param {org.sample.count} count
 * @transaction
 */
function count(count) {
  count.pollId.asks.forEach(function(ask) {
    var serializer = getSerializer()
    var serializer = getSerializer();
    var jsonObj = serializer.toJSON(ask);
    console.log("Ask: ", ask);
    console.log("Ask jsonObj: ", jsonObj);    
  });
}
```

Using this, I was able to create an `Ask` and then a `Poll` in which I feed the `Poll` into the transactions. Looking at my chaincode logs I can see that my obj has been printed correctly

```
Ask:  Resource {id=org.sample.count.Ask#striaweng}
Ask jsonObj:{$class:"org.sample.count.Ask",askId:"striaweng",title:"striawefawefng",options:["stawefring","stawefring","stawefring"],votes:[0,2,3,4,5]}
```

Maybe try this and see if it helps. Make sure you feed in the correct `Asset` and reference the right sub-properties.

Comment: Thanks, it has been very useful! I had a problem parsing the ID. I have another question: now I´ve incremented the number of votes but it doesn't change in the assets. Is it necessary to do some kind of "submit"? because the number of votes changes after finishing my function, but no in the asset

Comment: It is solved, it was necessary to write an `update` statement